# Spring Boot Rest API

Tags: spring, spring-boot, api, rest

I have an API with path params which I implemented using Spring boot

GET URL
/student/4/course/abc

No my question is if user enters
/student//course  or

/student/4/course/

Do I need to validate it and send message that invalid path params ?
Since it is not executing the controller function , How can I validate ?

Or as the URI itself is wrong default 404 is fine without any message .

I tried @Nonblank validation but still showing white label error page  .
Is Non blank validation is right for this case and will it execute as control might not go in the method as URI is wrong .

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a student assignment and I wouldn't realistically expect invalid urls to be handled gracefully, unless that's something your instructor has asked you to do. The default 404 page is expected and will work just fine.

In a production environment you can(should) use an @ExceptionHandler to catch and handle 404's.

@NonBlank is to ensure a text parameter is not empty. I wouldn't use it in this case.